# Is Firefox using its own isolated Certificate STore

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ssl, certificate

I am using the latest Firefox.

However, my campus uses their own certificate for all internet browsing and asks us to install **their certificate as Root CA**.

Since, i **don't trust** them with my personal data, but to browse easily, i am forced to install the Certificate.

Is it possible to install Certificate in **Firefox only**, without affecting my **PCs root store** and interfere with other browsers such as Chrome.
Moreover is it possible to have the certificate in **separate Mozilla Profile** or any other version i install simultaneously ???
Thanks.

Comment: Your campus requires the use of their certificate for regular internet browsing? What campus is it?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Google Chrome, firefox has its own certificate store separate from the system's.

To install a Root CA, go in the preferences of your firefox browser. 
In the advanced tab, there is a sub tab called Certificates/Encryption, depending on the OS and the version of firefox that you are using.

From there, you can manage everything related to certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Firefox allows you to install the certificate in a different profile.

- open Firefox (-ProfileManager, and eventually, --no-remote)
- Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced
- on tab Encryption, you have the button "View Certificates", which is where you can add or remove the certificates.